# How to remove all remote tracking branches that still exist on remote but no longer in my fetch refspec

Tags: git

I recently reorganized my refspec of `remote.origin.fetch` and now only fetch a small subset of branches from remote. However, `git branch -a` shows me a lot of remote branches that I fetched previously, although they are no longer fetched now. Using `git prune` does NOT help because those remote tracking branches do exist in remote.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer from **robrich** has a good hint: You can just remove every remote-tracking branch (or even the remote), and then use `git fetch` to grab only those you want now from scratch.

If you do try to remove the remote all together, you may want to backup your .git/config file, so that when you add the remote back later, you can pick up the per-remote setting from the backup.

However, removing remote does not remove the remote-tracking branches for me. Maybe my local repo is bad. For any one who has the same problem, what I ended up doing is:

```
# This deletes all remote tracking branches for all remotes. So be careful if you have multiple remotes.
git branch -r | xargs -L 1 git branch -rD
```

Also, I have a lot of tags from the remote, which slow things down. I did this too:

```
# Be careful! This deletes EVERY tag!
git tag | xargs -L 1 git tag -d
```

You may want to configure `git fetch` to not fetch all those tags back next time, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the remote and re-add it, then re-configure the `remote.origin.fetch`.  It's hitting the ant hill with a mallet, but it'll get the job done.  You'll still need to delete the local branches (if any), but that's a mere `git branch -D theOffendingBranchName`.

**Edit:**  If you're feeling adventurous, you could go pillage through `.git/refs/` deleting files you don't like.  Make a backup of your .git folder first though -- in case the pruning goes very wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turns out that `git remote rm` fails to remove remote-tracking branches, even after `git gc`. I ended up doing `git branch -D` for every remote-tracking branch.

Comment: Also, deleting .git/refs/remotes/origin does not help either. I suspect that many remote tracking branches are already packed and therefore do not appear as files there.

Comment: Good idea.  You could pillage through `.git/packed-refs`, though if deleting the remote worked, problem solved.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using git 2.8.1. It seems to be looking only for local branches `error: branch 'origin/master' not found.` To specify the remote tracking branch, I have to pass `r` to it with `git branch -rD origin/master`